# not being able to retrive friends data using Graph API of Faceboof SDK for unity?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

I am using facebook sdk for unity to get user's friends data. but in response i am not being able to get any information about user's friends.

here is the code i am using(using C# )

```
void Start () 
{
    FB.Init (onInitC, onHideU);
}

void onInitC()
{
    FB.Login ("public_profile,email,user_friends",loginCallB);
}

void onHideU(bool isGameShown)
{
    Debug.Log("Is game showing? " + isGameShown);
}

void loginCallB(FBResult result)
{
    Debug.Log ("loginCallB FBResult.Text=="+result.Text);
    FB.API ("/me/permissions", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, APICallB_permissions);

}

void APICallB_permissions(FBResult result)
{
    Debug.Log ("APICallB_permissions FBResult.Text=="+result.Text);
    FB.API ("/me/friends?fields=first_name,id", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, APICallB_friends);
}


void APICallB_friends(FBResult result)
{
    Debug.Log ("APICallB_friends FBResult.Text=="+result.Text);
```

**Log in consol is as follows :-**

```
loginCallB FBResult.Text=={"is_logged_in":true,"user_id":"XXXX","access_token":"XXXX","access_token_expires_at":"01/01/0001 00:00:00"}
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
LevelDesign:loginCallB(FBResult) (at Assets/Scripts_Custom/LevelDesign.cs:28)
Facebook.AbstractFacebook:OnAuthResponse(FBResult)
Facebook.EditorFacebook:MockLoginCallback(FBResult) (at Assets/Facebook/Scripts/EditorFacebook.cs:222)
Facebook.<Start>c__Iterator0:MoveNext()


APICallB_permissions FBResult.Text=={"data":[{"permission":"installed","status":"granted"},{"permission":"public_profile","status":"granted"},{"permission":"user_friends","status":"granted"}]}
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
LevelDesign:APICallB_permissions(FBResult) (at Assets/Scripts_Custom/LevelDesign.cs:35)
Facebook.<Start>c__Iterator0:MoveNext()


APICallB_friends FBResult.Text=={"data":[]}
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
LevelDesign:APICallB_friends(FBResult) (at Assets/Scripts_Custom/LevelDesign.cs:42)
Facebook.<Start>c__Iterator0:MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application was created after 30th April 2014, you will not be able to access the User's friends list anymore. The `/me/friends` API endpoint will only show you friends who also have the application installed.

If you are looking to invite friends to use your app, it first must be classified as a Game, and you will need to use the new `invitable_friends` API instead.

Call `/me/invitable_friends` to see a list of friends you can invite to use your application.

[More information here.](https://www.webniraj.com/2014/06/12/facebook-api-getting-friends-using-graph-api-2-0-and-php-sdk-4-0-x/)

Comment: replaced "friends" with "invitable_friends" but no luck still. and yes i already made this app classified as Game. do i need to submit this app to review on facebook ? because this is just a test app i am using to learn something. and documentation on facebook says for permissions other then public_profile,email,user_friends you need to  submit it for review first

Comment: also do i need to create it for the facebook canvas first and then switch to mobile platforms ?

Comment: You can create for mobile platforms straight away.